# How to push a file in Github repository

Tags: github

[image]
I have created a folder in my desktop which contains files which I want to push in already created Github repository.

When I'm pushing file its shows error that remote origin already exists.
How do I add these files?

Comment: Please mention the commands that you have used.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear because you aren't telling us exactly what you're doing, you haven't mentioned your error messages, and you've shared what _should_ be plain text as an image. Generally speaking screenshots shouldn't be used for text. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your local branch isn't up to date with the master branch. Which means that there are few commits which need to be pulled on to the local before making any push.

`git add * && git commit -m "Your Commit Message"` (If you haven't made any commits already.)

`git pull origin master`

`git push -u origin master`

Thanks!